# ng-bootstrap Tooltips & HTML Entries from a Database

Tags: javascript, html, angular, tooltip, ng-bootstrap

I have an issue where I can get things like  tags, line breaks, bulleted lists, etc.. in the ng-template contents for ng-bootstrap tooltips with test text, but when retrieving from the middle layers and database, it does not render in bold (in this case). For instance:

```
                  <label [for]="q.value.question.id">{{q.value.question.questinontext}}
                    <ng-template #tipContent data-html="true">{{q.value.question.descriptiontext}} TEST TEST <b>TEST</b></ng-template>
                    <span class="fa fa-question-circle" placement="bottom" [ngbTooltip]="tipContent" tooltipClass="custom-tooltip" data-html="true"></span>
                    <span class="required" *ngIf="measureUtilities.questionIsRequired(null, measure, q.value.question)==1"> *</span>
                  </label>
```

Will yield something that looks like this, despite having data-html="true" and knowing it works with hardcoded text.

[image]

Anyone have any ideas of things I can try or alternatives that might allow for something like this? See HTML Bindings section here (I pulled the data-html bit from somewhere else)

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tooltip/examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI for those who run into the same issue - you need to put this in a div tag within the ng-template tag and have innerHTML specified:

```
            <label [for]="q.value.question.id">{{q.value.question.questinontext}}
              <ng-template #tipContent> <div [innerHTML]="q.value.question.descriptiontext"></div></ng-template>
              <span class="fa fa-question-circle" placement="bottom" [ngbTooltip]="tipContent"></span>
              <span class="required" *ngIf="q.value.question.isrequired==1"> *</span>
            </label>
```

Answer (score 1):

The [stackblitz from the examples](https://stackblitz.com/run?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftooltip-tplcontent.html) shows how to use HTML in the tootli[ and it works. Looking into your code I can only say `data-html` attribute will not affect the tooltip behavior. I don't see any other issues. I would be able to provide more help if stackblitz with reproduction would be provided.